# Copy database without sysadmin permission

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy a production database (all tables, views and SP's) from a SQL server 2008 instance to my local development machine.

Since I only have access to the database and no administrative permissions on the server itself, I am unable to do the normal full backup/restore or even run the database copy wizard.

I guess I could script all the database objects and export/import data from the tables but that seems very tedious. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The only approach that I am aware of is to script all of the objects (tables, views etc...) and run them against a new database.

There are various database comparison tools that should be able do this automatically for you, although I can't remember which one I used last time I needed to do this, but these two look OK and are free

- http://www.sqldbtools.com/
- http://dbdiff.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much listed all the options. Since "they" don't want you to do it yourself, and since you require that data, then the best way would be to contact "them" and request that they prepare and send you a fresh backup of the database.

Comment: Yep, that's the official way but "they" have a very high reply latency so it'd be great to have a workaround for silly little things like this.